# Category theoretic description of construction of stage of Feistel network

Tags: category-theory, cryptography

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher#Design

> A Feistel network uses a round function, a function which takes two inputs – a data block and a subkey – and returns one output of the same size as the data block. In each round, the round function is run on half of the data to be encrypted, and its output is XORed with the other half of the data. This is repeated a fixed number of times, and the final output is the encrypted data. An important advantage of Feistel networks compared to other cipher designs such as substitution–permutation networks is that the entire operation is guaranteed to be invertible (that is, encrypted data can be decrypted), even if the round function is not itself invertible.

The trick here (at least, the trick I'm interested in) is that starting with *any* function $f(x)$, we can create an injective function by defining $g(x) = (x, f(x))$.

Is there a straightforward way to use products and functors in category theory to describe this operation?

Comment: what does the category theoretic approach bring to the problem? I would be interested to find out if there is something new in terms of cipher design or analysis that could be contributed by this abstract approach.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this particular case is trivial. I'm just starting to explore category theory and it felt like there should be an abstract way to describe the Feistel trick. On the broader topic, you might find https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.6488 interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if this answers your question (if not, please specify it), but for any morphism $f : X \to Y$ in a category with binary products we can produce its graph morphism $\Gamma_f : X \to X \times Y$ defined by $\Gamma_f(x) = (x,f(x))$ on [generalized elements](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/generalized+element), or equivalently $\mathrm{pr}_1 \circ \Gamma_f =  \mathrm{id}_X$ and $\mathrm{pr}_2 \circ \Gamma_f = f$. By its very construction this is a [split monomorphism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/split+monomorphism).